# Only display codenarc priorities 1 and 2 in Jenkins violations report

Tags: grails, jenkins, groovy, grails-plugin, codenarc

**Is there a way I can exclude priority 3 violations from the Jenkins graph?** The other codenarc report types like 'html' or 'sortable' have a [*maxPriority* option](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-HtmlReportWriter.html) which does exactly what I want, but that option doesn't exist for the type=xml report.

Help?

---

Details:

I use [codenarc](https://grails.org/plugin/codenarc) as a lint-like source code analysis tool for my Groovy / Grails project.

The Jenkins [Violations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations) supports codenarc (among others) and allows the Jenkins job to not only display an HTML codenarc report, but also Fail the build if, say, you have 1 or more high priority violations.

This is all great but I don't want any priority 3 (low level) violations to appear in the nifty graph which the violations plugin creates in Jenkins.

It's more an issue of visual appeal than anything else. I don't want low level violations to appear at all.

Am I left with only the option of removing all priority 3 references by post-processing the xml file that is initially generated? Regex to the rescue. In that case I guess I add a Build Step that is a Groovy Script which runs before the Violations are evaluated?